# How to add existing collection views to table view without losing table view cells in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, tableview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm trying to add two existing collection view cells with their own preferences to first two cells of my already existing table view WITHOUT losing other table view cells. Now every views are working good manually.
[This is my UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxWcb.jpg)

Collection V1:

```
import UIKit

final class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var images: UIImageView!
    public func configureCollection(photo: UIImage) {
        images.image = photo
        images.layer.cornerRadius = 12
       
    }

}
```

Collection V2:

```
import UIKit

final class SelectCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var selectionTextLabel: UILabel!
    public func confCollectionView(selectionText: String){
        selectionTextLabel.text = selectionText

    }
}
```

Table View

```
import UIKit

final class homePageTableView: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var productPhoto: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var productName: UILabel!
        public func configureHomeShop(photo: UIImage, item: String) {
        productName.text = item
        productPhoto.image = photo
    }
}
```

View controller where everything located:

```
class homeView: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionViewOne: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionViewTwo: UICollectionView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collectionViewOne.register(CollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "itemsCollectionViewCell")
        collectionViewTwo.register(SelectCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "SelectCollectionViewCell")
        collectionViewTwo.dataSource = self
        collectionViewTwo.delegate = self
        collectionViewOne.dataSource = self
        collectionViewOne.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
    }
    // **Functions**

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 100
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return itemsArray.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "shopCell", for: indexPath) as? homePageTableView else {
            fatalError()
        }
        
        cell.configureHomeShop(photo: photoArrayTV.first!, item: itemsArray.first!)
        return cell
    }
    
    // MARK: - CollectionView

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if collectionView == self.collectionViewOne{
            return imagesArray.count
            
        }else{
            return selectionArray.count
        }
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        
        if collectionView == self.collectionViewOne{

            guard let cellOne = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "firstCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as? CollectionViewCell else{
                fatalError()
            }
            cellOne.configureCollection(photo: imagesArray[imagesArray.count - indexPath.row - 1])
            return cellOne
            
        }else{

            guard let cellTwo = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "secondCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as? SelectCollectionViewCell else{
                fatalError()
            }
            cellTwo.confCollectionView(selectionText: selectionArray.last!)
            return cellTwo
        }
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the good approach for this, you have to add `collectionView` in the `tableViewHeader`

then whenever you scroll up your `tableView` your `collectionView` section will also scroll up

**to load cells on the specific indexes follow bellow steps:**

```
if(indexpath.row == 0){
//load first tableView cell with collection view 
}
else if (indexpath.row == 1){
//load second tableView cell with collection view
}
else{
//load table view cell here
}
```

Comment: Looks like it’s a good idea. Can u explain how to add collection view to the header of table view

Comment: you can also add them in single row cells as follow in this demo: https://slicode.com/collectionview-inside-tableview-cell-part-2/

Comment: look's like it's more easy to drag collection view to the top of table view. it work's great but i couldn't drag second collection view to the top. it moves under prototype cell. how to fix it?

Comment: follow the above link and fix tableView index 0 and 1 for collection view and remaining for tableView rows and if if this answer is working for you you can mark this answer correct thanks

Comment: i couldn't find how to set cells index path

Comment: how to set index path of collection view cell in table view?/

Comment: i can't mark comments because my level is too low but i created new answer about how to set cells index path https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65979974/how-to-set-collection-view-cells-indexpath-in-a-table-view      if u will answer as an answer i will mark it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52104047/how-to-properly-add-an-uicollectionview-inside-uitableviewcell-using-ios-12 here is a lot of examples you can get the idea from here

Comment: thank u but i only need to set the index path of cell. that's all

Comment: i updated the answer check and mark correct if it usefull

Comment: i'm sorry but when i'm loading collection view to the place where u commented, comes warning "Cannot convert return expression of type 'SelectCollectionViewCell' to return type 'UITableViewCell". please help with it

Comment: make a separate tableView cell where you will implement collection view and load that tableview cell to cellForRowAt function